# Creating MSI installation package using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows-installer

I have been working on a project involving MS access as database (ADODB). I have built and executed the project. However I am having troubles in making a package out of it for installation on some other PC. previously with VB6 I could do that with package deployment wizard and didn't have to worry about dependencies and all. Now I have no idea how to do this in VS2015. I have tried InstallShield and Visual Setup. Both are stuck with missing dependencies. One is NetFramework (can be installed manually) second is that target pc doesn't recognize ADODB string. Can anyone help me out in how to create this package that will transport all the required depencies and as a bonus it also installs NetFramework on target pc on its own (the way it happens in done installation of games with DirectX)

Thanks

Comment: Read up on the WiX toolset (https://wix.codeplex.com/). If your MSI will be fairly standard you'll be able to find examples on the web showing you how to get what you need out of it.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I am very new at this. I have tried the installation package but some dependency files are still missing. The applicatoin doesn't launch. Try-Catch statement revealed that the error is in connecting to database file. It doesn't load up. The same .exe I run on my own PC, and it works fine (my pc has Visual Studio 2015 installed so it does have the required environment). I will look into the wix tool you suggest.